# How to convert an array of arrays into a matrix?

Tags: arrays, julia

I can't find an answer to this simple question.

I have the following:

```
A(a,j)=[a*j*i*k for i in 1:2, k in 1:2];

B=[A(a,j) for a in 1:2, j in 1:2];
```

`B` is a an array of arrays: `2×2 Array{Array{Int64,2},2}`. This is useful to easily access the subarrays with indices (e.g., `B[2,1]`). However, I also need to convert `B` to a 4 by 4 matrix. I tried `hcat(B...)` but that yields a 2 by 8 matrix, and other options are worse (e.g., `cat(Test2...;dims=(2,1))`).

Is there an efficient way of writing `B` as a matrix while keeping the ability to easily access its subarrays, especially as `B` gets very large?

Comment: Do you mean doing something like `[B[1,1] B[1,2]; B[2,1] B[2,2]]` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Should have said it explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want this:

```
julia> hvcat(size(B,1), B...)
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  2   4
 2  4  4   8
 2  4  4   8
 4  8  8  16
```

or without defining `B`:

```
julia> hvcat(2, (A(a,j) for a in 1:2, j in 1:2)...)
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  2   4
 2  4  4   8
 2  4  4   8
 4  8  8  16
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
B = reduce(hcat, reduce(vcat, A(a,j) for a in 1:2) for j in 1:2)
```

---

**EDIT**: Actually this is very slow, I would recommend making a function, e.g.,

```
function buildB(A, n)
    A0 = A(1,1)
    nA = size(A0, 1)
    B = Array{eltype(A0),2}(undef, n * nA, n * nA)
    for a in 1:n, j in 1:n
        B[(a-1)*nA .+ (1:nA), (j-1)*nA .+ (1:nA)] .= A(a,j)
    end
    return B
end
```

or maybe consider a package like [BlockArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/BlockArrays.jl)?

---

**EDIT 2** This is an example with BlockArrays.jl:

```
using BlockArrays
function blockarrays(A, n)
    A0 = A(1,1)
    nA = size(A0, 1)
    B = BlockArray{eltype(A0)}(undef_blocks, fill(nA,n), fill(nA,n))
    for a in 1:n, j in 1:n
        setblock!(B, A(a,j), a, j)
    end
    return B
end
```

which should do what you want:

```
julia> B = blockarrays(A, 2)
2×2-blocked 4×4 BlockArray{Int64,2}:
 1  2  │  2   4
 2  4  │  4   8
 ──────┼───────
 2  4  │  4   8
 4  8  │  8  16

julia> getblock(B, 1, 2)
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  4
 4  8

julia> B[4,2]
8
```

Comment: Thanks! This one seems like a good option, but @Bogumił-Kamiński's answer seems to do it nicely so I'm accepting that answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, Bogumil's answer is good! The benefit of BlockArrays is that you have the standard indexing but you also get the subarray/block indexing, which is what I thought you wanted there:
> Is there an efficient way of writing B as a matrix while keeping the ability to easily access its subarrays, especially as B gets very large?